# Flutter: sliverAppBar resize issue on list scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make sliverAppBar resized while scrolling list below it.

Now there are two issues:

1) sliverAppBar doesn't resize while I am scrolling list ([screenshot](https://ibb.co/xJcr2wr))

2) I can't find example/solution how to resize child content of sliverAppBar when it change height ([screenshot](https://ibb.co/Ph8GCsD))

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar( // <-- how to resize on scrolling ListView?
          expandedHeight: 200.0,
          floating: false,
          pinned: true,
          flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row( // <-- how to make it flexible/resizable?
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/user.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      width: 120,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: false,
            itemCount: widget.europeanCountries.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(widget.europeanCountries[index]),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _incrementCounter,
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [FlexibleSpaceBar] and [SliverList]

- [SliverList] can change the size of [sliverAppBar] when scrolling the list
- [FlexibleSpaceBar] prevents border overflow

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            floating: true,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, bc) {
                double size = min(
                    // bc.constrainHeight() - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                    bc.constrainHeight(),
                    120);
                return FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  // title: Container(
                  //   width: size,
                  //   height: size,
                  //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  //     shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  //     image: DecorationImage(
                  //       image: NetworkImage(
                  //           'https://i.loli.net/2019/08/09/OvVzMqpF3jmI8lE.jpg'),
                  //       fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  //     ),
                  //   ),
                  // ),
                  background: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: size,
                      height: size,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://i.loli.net/2019/08/09/OvVzMqpF3jmI8lE.jpg'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            //
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("Text"),
                );
              },
              childCount: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now scrolling works as expected. But background property in sliverApBar doesn't resize child icon on scroll, it just fades the icon as background.

Comment: @mr.boris I updated the answer and hope that you can find inspiration.